# macos catalina version 10.15 - Kali linux installation

Tags: kali-linux, macos, laptop

I'm trying to download Kali Linux Live Boot on my macOS since I don't have the space with Virtualbox. My system does not have sufficient space to install successfully. Is there a way to do so with persistence, using an SSD? I've used some of the GB on my SSD and would not like to lose anything on it. I heard there is a way with virtual box. My SSD has 498 GB and I can't figure out how to install it correctly. If someone has the answers please explain how I can do this.

Thank you in advance!